# Screenreader focus lost/cannot be regained in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a React app where users go from Page A -> Page B.

After going from Page A to B, though, the Mac OS X screenreader focus is lost and even though the keyboard focus is set and the user can scroll through various elements on that page using the keyboard, the screenreader does not move. The black outline for the screenreader remains on the position where it was from Page A.

If I turn off the screenreader and then turn it back on when on Page B, then it works on Page B all of a sudden.

Is this likely related to the shadow DOM? If so, how can I solve this?

Comment: How are they going from page A to page B, I presume AJAX navigation? If so is your router set up correctly? Is the element they click on to move pages still visible when the page changes? Are you managing focus in any way when the page changes? Are you attempting to notify users when the page changes with `aria-live` or doing anything else unusual? Is the problem only on VoiceOver or does it persist on other screen readers? Have you tried this in other browsers and does the problem persist there? What makes you believe it is shadow DOM, are you getting any errors? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes react-router navigation which uses HTML5 push API. The router is working correctly as far as I know. When the next page loads, then the focus is set on an element in the new page. No using `aria-live` or anything like that. Not sure about other screen readers, but it does not work on Chrome. I just tested Safari and it works fine. Shadow DOM was just a guess in that it could be confusing the screen reader possibly by modifying the DOM.

Comment: Sounds like focus is being set too early (Chrome V8 engine making some micro optimisation that is unexpected could be a cause? Unsure without any code to look at) or something isn't right where an element is being re-rendered and destroying focus, as a quick test can you artificially add a delay into your function that sets the focus after an additional 1 second and see if this corrects.

Comment: Will give that a try. Though even when focus is changed via the keyboard within the React app the focus ring moves around within the app but the screenreader still does not gain focus so I am doubtful.

Comment: I tried setting a 1s interval to continually bring focus to an element on the new page where it should be focused but it still did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie any tips on how to further debug this?

Comment: Interestingly, I tried using the Accessibility Inspector on Mac OS X to debug the a11y tree, but on Page B it is just considered one big group with no children. However, if I turn off and turn on the screen reader on Page B, all of a sudden the tree gets parsed.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie turns out it was a bug in Chrome, updating fixed the issue.

Comment: Super, glad you got it sorted.